# eclipse formatting -- <script type="text/ng-template"...> tag not support html text

Tags: html, angularjs, eclipse

html syntax in  tag not support html text formats like text color, auto complete so on. all html syntax appearing black color. i tired with angularjs plugin but cannot find the solution.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.htm">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="card-deck-wrapper">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <p>Test 01</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-deck">
                <p>Test 01</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

[capture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCy7u.png)

[image]

Comment: You should put your html tags in component.html file

Comment: i am using jsp in this project

Comment: It probably thinks that text inside <script> is JavaScript and not HTML

Answer (score 0):

Content assist and syntax coloring inside of a script tag are controlled by the value of the type attribute. You may know what an ng-template type means, but you don't have a plug-in installed that tells the HTML and JSP editors what that means. For unknown types (and language values), this is what is supposed to happen. The safest thing they can do for your data is be completely hands-off.